# KILL QUERY Flooding in General Query log for MySQL 8.0.25

Tags: c#, .net, mysql-connector, mysql-8.0

We have two MySQL servers in master master replication. We can see many `KILL QUERY` statements in MySQL general log specific to stored procedures as below :

```
2024-03-20T21:54:45.056981+05:30        12996 Query     CALL tc_updatemostinterestedinquiry(9546, 1446507, 3)
2024-03-20T21:54:45.068626+05:30        14167 Connect   stg_abweb_write@10.20.171.33 on autobiz using TCP/IP
2024-03-20T21:54:45.068978+05:30        14167 Query     SET NAMES utf8mb4
2024-03-20T21:54:45.069238+05:30        14167 Query     KILL QUERY 12996
2024-03-20T21:54:45.069497+05:30        14167 Quit
2024-03-20T21:54:45.069586+05:30        12996 Query     DO SLEEP(0)
2024-03-20T21:54:45.070287+05:30        12996 Query     SET NAMES utf8mb4
```

These stored procedures are called from a .NET application where we use dapper library version 1.60.6

```
<PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="1.60.6" />
```

Stored procedure call syntax in the application is

```
 con.Connection.Query<dynamic>("stored_procedure_name", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

We use **MysqlConnector** version 1.3.8.

1. After removing Connection Admin and Super privilege which is required to run the `KILL QUERY` statement from the MySQL user we observe `KILL QUERY` statements still exists in the general log. You can check about the privileges requirement [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/kill.html).
2. This `KILL QUERY` statement creates a new connection every time to the MySQL server for execution.
3. We have read about [MysqlConnector Command Cancellation](https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/command-cancellation/) which tells there is a possibility of command timeout. But when we call these stored procedures without any commands in it from the application they still give out `KILL QUERY` in general log. There are no such long running queries in stored procedures.
4. When connecting to MySQL server via workbench and calling same stored procedures we don't face any `KILL QUERY` statements.

We have been facing this problem since quite long, please help. We dont wish to have these statements in our general log as it bombards the server with new connections.

Comment: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amysql-net%2FMySqlConnector%20%22Kill%20query%22&type=code You are likely calling `Cancel` as per https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/blob/033abeacbc1fc997bca49a37b5d7522c5b095d99/docs/content/overview/command-cancellation.md?plain=1#L20 . Or `CommandTimeout` is being exceeded.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: `There are no such long running queries in stored procedures.` How are you **certain** of that?

Comment: About the long running queries, when we do not have any statements in the stored procedures still a KILL QUERY is logged @mjwills

Comment: Try reproduce your own statements with single procedure in db in dev env. The problem is in your code. KILL QUERY is cancellation, which happens manually on rollbacks or on timeouts. You probably swallowing some retries in your code.

Comment: We have resolved the problem. Problem was the Query function called from dapper. When we used QueryAsync we did not notice such behavior in general log.